# Calculate the maximum value of a column satisfying the condition in each row

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate the maximum of column 'value', where its timestamp must be between timestsmp_pre and timestamp_post.

input:

```
ID          timestamp  Value    timestamp_Pre   timestamp_Post
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:27     33    2023-1-5 06:33:20    2023-1-5 06:33:10
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:33     22    2023-1-5 06:33:30    2023-1-5 06:33:27
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:39     44    2023-1-5 06:33:33    2023-1-5 06:33:28
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:45     67    2023-1-5 06:33:39    2023-1-5 06:33:26
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:51     99    NA                   2023-1-5 06:33:44
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:57     88    2023-1-5 06:33:44    NA
```

output:

```
ID          timestamp  Value    timestamp_Pre   timestamp_Post      Max_value
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:27     33    2023-1-5 06:33:20    2023-1-5 06:33:10  NA
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:33     22    2023-1-5 06:33:30    2023-1-5 06:33:27  33
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:39     44    2023-1-5 06:33:33    2023-1-5 06:33:28  22
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:45     67    2023-1-5 06:33:39    2023-1-5 06:33:26  44
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:51     NA    NA                   2023-1-5 06:33:44  NA
aa  2023-1-5 06:33:57     88    2023-1-5 06:33:44    NA             NA
```

For example, the row number four, the max_value must be the maximum value of 'Value' whose timestamp is >2023-1-5 06:33:26 and less than 2023-1-5 06:33:35. There is a chance of having null value in columns(Value, timestamp_Pre, timestamp_Post).

code used:

```
m=(df['timestamp']<df['timestamp_Pre']) & (df['timestamp']>df['timestamp_Post']) 
df['Max_Value']=df.where(m).groupby('id)['value'].transform('max')
```

I am getting null value in all row in column 'Max_Value' with the above code

I have implemented the solution using for loop as below. But I need the solution without using for loop

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    df_temp=df[(df['timestamp']<=df['timestamp_Pre'].iloc[i]) & (df['timestamp']>=df['timestamp_Post'].iloc[i])
    df.iloc[i]['Max_value']=df_temp['Value'].max()
```

Comment: Your input is inconsistent. Timestamp is always greater than Pre and Post and never between them.

Comment: yes... you are right... I need to get the maximum value from previous rows satisfying the timestamp condition

Comment: Why the column Pre change between your input and your output?

Comment: Typo error in the input. Updated the same. Thanks

Comment: Ok, now your data is cleaned, can you explain me how the value 33 is set to the second row please? I think there is a shift but the boolean mask is always False.

Comment: now data is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this problem with numpy broadcasting:

```
cols = ['timestamp', 'Value', 'timestamp_Pre', 'timestamp_Post']
def max_value(df):
    # Explode into variables
    ts, val, pre, post = df[cols].values.T

    # Compute vectorized boolean mask
    m = (post <= ts[:, None]) & (ts[:, None] <= pre)

    # Select right values (0 when mask is False)
    out = np.max(m * val[:, None], axis=0)

    # Replace 0 by NaN
    out[~m.any(axis=0)] = np.nan

    # Return a DataFrame with the same index as original
    return pd.DataFrame(out, index=df.index, columns=['Max'])

df['Max'] = df.groupby('ID', group_keys=False).apply(max_value)['Max']
```

Output:

```
>>> df

   ID           timestamp  Value       timestamp_Pre      timestamp_Post  Max
0  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:27     33 2023-01-05 06:33:20 2023-01-05 06:33:10  NaN
1  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:33     22 2023-01-05 06:33:30 2023-01-05 06:33:27   33
2  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:39     44 2023-01-05 06:33:33 2023-01-05 06:33:28   22
3  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:45     67 2023-01-05 06:33:39 2023-01-05 06:33:26   44
4  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:51     99                 NaT 2023-01-05 06:33:44  NaN
5  aa 2023-01-05 06:33:57     88 2023-01-05 06:33:44                 NaT  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to solve your problem but for a better understanding where is it.

> I am getting null value in all row in column 'Max_Value' with the above code

Yes because your boolean mask `m` is always False.

```
# Your boolean mask
m1 = df['timestamp_Post'] < df['timestamp']
m2 = df['timestamp'] < df['timestamp_Pre']
m = m1 & m2
```

Reorganize data to see the problem. I removed date part because it's irrelevant here as all dates are the same:

```
>>> pd.concat([df['timestamp_Post'].dt.time,
               df['timestamp'].dt.time,
               df['timestamp_Pre'].dt.time,
               m, m1, m2], axis=1, keys=['Post', 'Time', 'Pre', 'm1&m2', 'm1', 'm2'])

       Post      Time       Pre  m1&m2     m1     m2
0  06:33:10  06:33:27  06:33:20  False   True  False
1  06:33:27  06:33:33  06:33:30  False   True  False
2  06:33:28  06:33:39  06:33:33  False   True  False
3  06:33:26  06:33:45  06:33:39  False   True  False
4  06:33:44  06:33:51       NaT  False   True  False
5       NaT  06:33:57  06:33:44  False  False  False
#      Your mask is always False --^   because   ^-- Pre is always less than Time
```

So whatever the following code, using `df.where` give you only `NaN/NaT` everywhere:

```
>>> df.where(m)
    ID timestamp  Value timestamp_Pre timestamp_Post
0  NaN       NaT    NaN           NaT            NaT
1  NaN       NaT    NaN           NaT            NaT
2  NaN       NaT    NaN           NaT            NaT
3  NaN       NaT    NaN           NaT            NaT
4  NaN       NaT    NaN           NaT            NaT
5  NaN       NaT    NaN           NaT            NaT
```

Comment: I have updated the code using for loop. I need the solution without for loop.